# Testing for the existence of a frame in Edge

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

I have the following test that works in every browser that I've tested with besides Microsoft legacy Edge.

```
        var frame_name = window.parent.frames[1].name;

        if (window.parent[frame_name].frames[1].frames[1]) {
           //Edge thinks this is true, 
        }
```

In legacyEdge it goes in there even though it's false.  In Chrome, etc. it see it as not true.  If I look at the value in the Edge debugger tools I see:

```
window.parent[frame_name].frames[1].frames[1]   [object Window]
__proto__   [object WindowPrototype]
{error} Permission denied
```

Is there any way I can test for the existence of the frame in Edge?

Answer (score 0):

I try to make a test with the **MS Edge legacy 44.18362.449.0** version and found that the code works fine in it.

Tested code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<h1>The iframe element</h1>

<iframe src="http://your_site/childpage.html">
</iframe>
<script>
if (window.parent.frames[1].frames[1]) {
   //Edge thinks this is true, 
   alert("found...");
   console.log(window.parent.frames[1].frames[1]);
}
else
{
alert("not forund...");
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Output:

[image]

It can posible that you are facing this issue due to cache. I suggest you try to clear the cache and again try to test the code.

If there is only 1 iframe on the page then you can use the code below.

```
if (window.parent.frames[0]) 
{
   
}
```

you can also try to find the iframe by its ID or Name like below.

```
<iframe src="http://your_site/childpage.html" id="frame1">
</iframe>

var element =  document.getElementById('frame1');
if (typeof(element) != 'undefined' && element != null)
{
   alert("found...");
}
```

Comment: I tweaked the code to more closely match my actual code.

Comment: I also tested your modified code but it shows error in the console. The error occurs because the frames[1].frames[1] is not available. So still the Edge browser shows the correct result. I want to confirm with you which version of the Edge legacy browser you are using for making this test?